# Did Capital One ever start reporting credit limits to the Credit Agencies for Credit card accounts?

Tags: credit-card

As described in this [article from 2005](http://www.bestcredit.com/credit-repair/capital-ones-evil-practices-affect-credit-rating.html) Capital One has done some shady things in the past in the way they report to credit bureaus. Specifically they don't disclose your credit limit to the credit agencies forcing them to use your highest balance as a proxy in your credit score calculation. If you never charge much on the card it will result in an inaccurate credit utilization ratio that hurts your credit score.

I'd pretty much sworn off using cards from them because of this, but they have a really excellent cash back card that I'm considering now and I want to know if they have changed their practices since 2005 regarding disclosing credit limits to the agencies. Does anyone here know?

Comment: Yikes! After reading their ["privacy" policy](http://www.capitalone.com/protection/privacy/2011_privacy_notice_eng.pdf?linkid=WWW_Z_Z_Z_PROPR_C1_01_T_PROPRNE) I changed my mind about getting the card. Still interested in the answer though.

Comment: Nothing comes for free you know. The excellent cash back card included.

Comment: True, but it should at least be free after you stop being a customer.

Comment: Closed accounts are reported for a time (7 years?) before falling off the report.

Comment: No, the privacy policy says they can share your information with marketing partners even after you close your accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they did stop the practice in 2007.  See this article from the Seattle Times for reference:  http://seattletimes.nwsource.com/html/realestate/2003820586_harney05.html